How to get around the Line Limit in Pine Editor
I'm trying to draw trendlines for the last year on a chart in Trading View, and I keep hitting the limit of 500 lines.  Does anyone know how to get around this?
I read in another post that you can do this by using an if look to change the X2 variable in the line.new command.  What do I set this too so that way it's not counting the total number on current bar?
line.new(x1, y1, x2, y2, xloc, extend, color, style, width) → series line
Here is the other post I'm referencing.
line.new() draws only for current month and not drawn on previous months
I tried playing around with the X2 using xloc etc.  But not sure how to make it dynamic for each bar so that way I don't hit the 500 line limit.

Unfortunately there is no workaround. The referred post suggests a solution to a bug that the asker added a new line on every single bar. Setting x2 has nothing to do with the limit. You can simply update existing lines by that. You could try polylines as an addition (limit 100), though that would be really ugly so I definitely would not suggest it.
